# Postgresql: How to merge 2 queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a case where I need to combine 2 queries to get an expected rersult:

I have 2 tables:

student

```
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | name  | ...                                |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| 1    | Tom   | ...                                |
| 2    | Mary  | ...                                |
| 3    | Peter | ...                                |
| 4    | Laura | ...                                |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

color

```
+------+-------+
| id   | color |
+------+-------+
| 1    | red   |
| 2    | blue  |
+------+-------+
```

I have 2 queries

```
//Select all student
select name from student

//Select a random color
select color from color
order by random()
limit 1
```

How can I merge results of 2 queries to get the final result.

```
 +------+-------+-------+
 | id   | name  | team  |
 +------+-------+-------+
 | 1    | Tom   | red   |
 | 2    | Mary  | red   |
 | 3    | Peter | blue  |
 | 4    | Laura | red   |
 +------+-------+-------+
```

The value in column 'team' is random value from table 'color'.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cross join of both tables and `distinct on` with appropriate `order by`:

```
select distinct on(s.id, name) s.id, name, color
from student s
cross join color
order by 1, 2, random()
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5fce/17)

Note that

```
order by 1, 2, random()
```

means to order by first, second column and then by random() and is equivalent to

```
order by s.id, name, random()
```

[Vide the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first. (...) The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

Comment: It worked like a charm, can you explain me more about order by 1, 2, random()?

Comment: you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select S.ID,S.Name,C.color as Team
from student s inner join color c on s.ID=c.ID
```

Comment: No, it will return only student 1 and 2, not all students